# Is there another way to create a backrground task without using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-background

I have an app that can download data from URL by using `HttpURLConnection`. I have tried using `AsyncTask` to create a background task, but it's not effective to pause and resume the download. It can cancel the download only. I thought there is another way to do it.

**Question:**  Is there another way to create a backrground task without using `AsyncTask`? If there are a lot of the ways, what are those ways?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can start a new thread and do whatever work you want

Comment: thanks, i'm trying it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For downloading data, you might use the [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) service.

More generally speaking, you could use [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) as a fairly simple alternative to AsyncTask. One downside is it doesn't come with a built-in way to transport data to the Main Thread. You might use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or the [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) for this purpose.

Comment: `@Barend`: Could this way displays a notification while running along with the icon and download speed?

Comment: You can get a status icon for free using the [`VISIBILITY_VISIBLE` notification property](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#VISIBILITY_VISIBLE) on your `DownloadManager.Request`. I don't know about showing the download speed.